# excel concatenate 3 cells

Tags: excel, if-statement, concatenation

my question is when ever i try any combination i should get one of the result
row 1 is first letter of cells 
row 2 is if Cell A is blank then two letter of Cell B then one letter of Cell C 
row 3 is if Cell A and Cell C is blank then three letter of Cell B
row 4 is if Cell C is blank then one letter of Cell A then two letter of Cell B
combine all four row in one row any combination i should get one of the result

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Eat | Sleep | Repeat | ESR |
|  | Sleep | Repeat | SlR |
|  | Sleep |  | Sle |
| Eat | Sleep |  | ESl |

```
D1 formula =Concatenate(Left(A1,1),Left(B1,1),Left(C1,1)) 
D2 formula =Concatenate(Left(B2,2),Left(C2,1)) 
D3 formula =Concatenate(Left(B3,3)) 
D4 formula =Concatenate(Left(A4,1),Left(B4,2))
```

```
D1 formula =(LEFT(A1,1)&LEFT(B1,1)&LEFT(C1,1))
D2 formula =(LEFT(B2,2)&LEFT(C2,1))
D3 formula =(LEFT(B3,3)) 
D4 formula =(LEFT(A4,1)&LEFT(B4,2))
```

combine all in one when entered any of the order display specific answer

[image]

Comment: What about =left(A1,1)&left(B1,1)

Comment: it only works for row 4

Comment: My point was "&" is equivalent to "concatenate()" in many situations... but if you like typing.

Comment: @SolarMike i got your point & is also good updated in question

Comment: What is your question? What you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just combine all your conditions into a single formula with SEVERAL if:

[image]

```
=IF(COUNTA(A1:C1)=3;LEFT(A1;1)&LEFT(B1;1)&LEFT(C1;1);IF(AND(A1="";COUNTA(B1:C1)=2);LEFT(B1;2)&LEFT(C1;1);IF(AND(A1="";C1="";B1<>"");LEFT(B1;3);IF(AND(COUNTA(A1:B1)=2;C1="");LEFT(A1;1)&LEFT(B1;2);"No match"))))
```

Indented:

```
=IF(COUNTA(A1:C1)=3;
    LEFT(A1;1)&LEFT(B1;1)&LEFT(C1;1);
    IF(AND(A1="";COUNTA(B1:C1)=2);
        LEFT(B1;2)&LEFT(C1;1);
        IF(AND(A1="";C1="";B1<>"");
            LEFT(B1;3);
            IF(AND(COUNTA(A1:B1)=2;C1="");
                LEFT(A1;1)&LEFT(B1;2);
                "No match")
            )
        )
    )
```

Comment: replace ; with ,

Comment: @ManojChurya That depends on your Excel settings. In my setup, I use semicolon instead of comma to separate arguments of functions :)

Comment: how to use proper function in the code because it is case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(COUNTA(A1:C1)=3,
    LEFT(A1,1)&LEFT(B1,1)&LEFT(C1,1),
    IF(AND(A1="",COUNTA(B1:C1)=2),
        LEFT(B1,2)&LEFT(C1,1),
        IF(AND(A1="",C1="",B1<>""),
            LEFT(B1,3),
            IF(AND(COUNTA(A1,B1)=2,C1=""),
                LEFT(A1,1)&LEFT(B1,2),
                "No match")
            )
        )
    )
```